# Can we deny a java object from serialization other than giving transient keyword

Tags: java, serialization, java-custom-serialization

We can avoid serialising fields by using the `transient` keyword.
Is there any other way of doing that?

Comment: i got this question...asking whether we can do it through native ..

Comment: For what purpose? Why is transient not a good solution for your use-cases?

Comment: @Bombe/@GaryF: curiosity is always a valid reason.

Comment: @Biju The question is still, why?  Why do it through native?  @Robert-Muneanu Curiosity is always a valid reason to ask a question, but "You shouldn't do this" is often a valid answer to the question.

Comment: no.no importance for..native..leave that native..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/security.html

> SUMMARY:Preventing Serialization of
>   Sensitive Data   Fields containing
>   sensitive data should not be
>   serialized; doing so exposes their
>   values to any party with access to the
>   serialization stream. There are
>   several methods for preventing a field
>   from being serialized:
>
> 1. Declare the field as private transient.
> 2. Define the serialPersistentFields
>      field of the class in question, and
>      omit the field from the list of
>      field descriptors.
> 3. Write a class-specific serialization
>      method (i.e., writeObject or
>      writeExternal) which does not write
>      the field to the serialization
>      stream (i.e., by not calling
>      ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject).

Here are some links.

[Declaring serialPersistenetFields.](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/index.html?page=3)

[Serialization architecture specification.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html)

[Security in Object Serialization.](http://ftp.ida.liu.se/~TDDB32/kursbibliotek/BlueJ/docs/guide/serialization/spec/security.html)

Comment: Declaring serialPersistenetFields - This is done using a special static final variable called serialPersistentFields.

Comment: Hi, how about declaring the field as `static final` (this is assuming that the value is a constant)? c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132646/1168041

Answer (score 9):

If for some reason transient doesn't suit, you can do the serialization directly by overriding the [writeObject and readObject](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) methods. Then you can include or omit any fields you need.

Answer (score 8):

This is what transient means as a a keyword. Its whole purpose is to stop the serialization of the data for whatever reason.

If you wanted a finer grain control over the process you can use the writeObject/readObject methods that the ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream use as part of the serialization process, and you could combine that with some custom annotations or any logic you wanted.

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
 throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
 throws IOException
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own protocol with the [Externalizable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface, that in my opinion is a nicer than Serializable since it doesn't contains private methods hooked by the JVM (`writeObject` and `readObject`). Instead of implementing the `Serializable` interface, you can implement `Externalizable`, which contains two methods:

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException;
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

Unlike using `Serializable` nothing is provided for free now, though. That is, **the protocol is entirely in your hands**, overring transient/non triansient fields, etc.