# Spark and Not Serializable DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-spark

I'm trying to use the DateTimeFormatter from java.time.format in Spark but it appears to be not serializable. This is the relevant chunk of code:

```
val pattern = "<some pattern>".r
val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("<some non-ISO pattern>")

val logs = sc.wholeTextFiles(path)

val entries = logs.flatMap(fileContent => {
    val file = fileContent._1
    val content = fileContent._2
    content.split("\\r?\\n").map(line => line match {
      case pattern(dt, ev, seq) => Some(LogEntry(LocalDateTime.parse(dt, dtFormatter), ev, seq.toInt))
      case _ => logger.error(s"Cannot parse $file: $line"); None
    })
  })
```

How can I avoid the `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` exception? Is there a better library to parse timestamps? I've read that Joda is also not serializable and has been incorporated in Java 8's time library.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can avoid serialization in two ways:

1. Assuming its value can be constant, place the formatter in an `object` (making it "static"). This would mean that the static value can be accessed within each worker, instead of the driver serializing it and sending to worker:

   ```
   object MyUtils {
     val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("<some non-ISO pattern>")
   }

   import MyUtils._
   logs.flatMap(fileContent => {
     // can safely use formatter here
   })
   ```
2. instantiate it per record inside the anonymous function. This carries some performance penalty (as the instantiation will happen over and over, per record), so only use this option if the first can't be applied:

   ```
   logs.flatMap(fileContent => {
     val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("<some non-ISO pattern>")
     // use formatter here
   })
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to make the DateTimeFormatter *transient*. This tells the JVM/Spark that the variable is not to be serialized, and instead constructed from scratch. For something that is cheap to construct per executor, like a DateTimeFormatter, this is a good approach.

Here's [an article that describes this in more detail](https://nathankleyn.com/2017/12/29/using-transient-and-lazy-vals-to-avoid-spark-serialisation-issues/).

Comment: Big misser this serialization aspect / problem.