# How to get Min, Max and Length between dates for each year?

Tags: scala, date, max, rdd, min

I have an rdd with type RDD[String] as an example here is a part of it as such:

```scala
1990,1990-07-08
1994,1994-06-18
1994,1994-06-18
1994,1994-06-22
1994,1994-06-22
1994,1994-06-26
1994,1994-06-26
1954,1954-06-20
2002,2002-06-26
1954,1954-06-23
2002,2002-06-29
1954,1954-06-16
2002,2002-06-30
...
```

result:
(1982,52)
(2006,64)
(1962,32)
(1966,32)
(1986,52)
(2002,64)
(1994,52)
(1974,38)
(1990,52)
(2010,64)
(1978,38)
(1954,26)
(2014,64)
(1958,35)
(1998,64)
(1970,32)

```
I group it nicely, but my problem is this v.size part, I do not know to to calculate that length.

Just to put it in perspective, here are expected results:

It is not a mistake that there is two times for 2002. But ignore that.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define date format:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

and order:

```
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(_.toEpochDay)
```

create a function that receives "v" and returns MAX(date_of_matching_year) - MIN(date_of_matching_year)) = LENGTH (in days):

```
def f(v: Iterable[Array[String]]): Int = {
    val parsedDates = v.map(LocalDate.parse(_(1), formatter))
    parsedDates.max.getDayOfYear - parsedDates.min.getDayOfYear
```

then replace the v.size with f(v)

Comment: What is the type of v? v: ..? I tried int, but map is not for int

Comment: ```scala
scala> val evega = concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => (k, f(v))}
<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[Array[String]]
 required: Array[String]
       val evega = concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => (k, f(v))}
                                                                                              ^
```
I tried this

Comment: And function is:
```scala
scala> def f(v: Array[String]): Int = {
     |     val parsedDates = v.map(LocalDate.parse(_, formatter))
     |     parsedDates.max.getDayOfYear - parsedDates.min.getDayOfYear}
f: (v: Array[String])Int
```

Comment: I have edited my answer, V is a collection of all the rows that match the same key. Since every row is an array (because of the .split(",")) it is an Iterable[Array[String]] . Now what I changed in my answer is going through all of the rows (with the flatmap) and parse the date on the second column and return it.

Comment: Why does this happen?
```scala
<console>:37: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1(1))
           val parsedDates = v.flatMap(LocalDate.parse(_(1), formatter))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error on my end. Try using map instead of flatMap. (I changed it in my answer) Did it help?>

Comment: I fixed it, but now I get a org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592811/task-not-serializable-java-io-notserializableexception-when-calling-function-ou

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592742/spark-scala-task-not-serializable-error?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132451/spark-and-not-serializable-datetimeformatter
I tried all of those and none work.
The error remains:
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter