# How to properly iterate over Array[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a function in scala which I send arguments to, I use it like this:

```scala
val evega = concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => (k, f(v))}
```

My function f is:

```scala
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(_.toEpochDay)
def f(v: Array[String]): Int = {
  val parsedDates = v.map(LocalDate.parse(_, formatter))
  parsedDates.max.getDayOfYear - parsedDates.min.getDayOfYear}
```

And this is the error I get:

```scala
 found   : Iterable[Array[String]]
 required: Array[String]
```

I already tried using:

```scala
val evega = concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => (k, for (date <- v) f(date))}
```

But I get massive errors.

Just to get a better picture, data in concat is:

```scala
1974,1974-06-22
1966,1966-07-20
1954,1954-06-19
1994,1994-06-27
1954,1954-06-26
2006,2006-07-04
2010,2010-07-07
1990,1990-06-30
...
```

It is type RDD[String].
How can I properly iterate over that and get a single Int from that function f?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? This will be easier for people to answer if they know the format of the data you are processing. Specifically, the content structure of ```concat```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDD types alongside your pipeline are:

- `concat.map(_.split(","))` gives an `RDD[Array[String]]`

  - for instance `Array("1954", "1954-06-19")`
- `concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0))` gives `RDD[(String, Array[String])]`

  - for instance `("1954", Array("1954", "1954-06-19"))`
- `concat.map(_.split(",")).keyBy(_(0)).groupByKey()` gives `RDD[(String, Iterable[Array[String]])]`

  - for instance `Iterable(("1954", Iterable(Array("1954", "1954-06-19"), Array("1954", "1954-06-24"))))`

Thus when you `map` at the end, the type of values is `Iterable[Array[String]]`.

Since your input is `"1974,1974-06-22"`, the solution could consist in replacing your `keyBy` transformation by a `map`:

```
input.map(_.split(",")).map(x => x(0) -> x(1)).groupByKey().map{case (k, v) => (k, f(v))}
```

Indeed, `.map(x => x(0) -> x(1))` (instead of `.map(x => x(0) -> x)` whose `keyBy(_(0))` is syntactic sugar for) will provide for the value the second element of the split array instead of the array itself. Thus giving `RDD[(String, String)]` during this second step rather than `RDD[(String, Array[String])]`.

Comment: Indeed, you can cast your `v` as an `Array`: `v.toArray`. But it might probably be safer for your function to accept an iterable to avoid out of memory issues.

Comment: I tried that already, I get this error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Comment: This is something else, the next issue to solve after solving the first one; now that the code compiles up to the call of `f`. It most probably comes from your use of the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132646/9297144).

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to replicate this on your repl. This happens at run time when you initialize a variable on the driver, and then try to use it on one of the workers. Please open a new question if needed as it's quite far from this question's initial problem.