# Task not serializable Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to traverse 2 different dataframes and in the process to check if the values in one of the dataframe lie in the specified set of values but I get org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable.

How can I improve my code to fix this error?

Here is how it looks like now:

```
private val unix_epoch = udf[Long, String, String]{ (date, time) =>
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd HHmmSS").parseDateTime(s"$date $time").getSeconds
  }

for {
      helpers <- helperFeed.dfFromDate(helperStartDateTime)
      dstHours <- feed.dfFromDate(startDateTime).map(_.select($"hour").distinct().as[Int].collect().toSeq)
    } {
     sparkSession.delta(srcPath).map { srcFeed =>

val srcHours = srcConversions
          .withColumn("hour", unix_epoch($"event_date", $"event_time"))
          .where($"hour" isin (dstHours: _*))
```

I suppose that this error appears after adding where clause with a filter. But how else can I implement it? I also tried just joining srcHours and dstHours as dataframes but I got the same error.

Update: dfFromDate just limits values in the dataframe by comparing them with the startdate (should be > startdate)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132451/spark-and-not-serializable-datetimeformatter#36132646

Comment: Do not know how to fix but very likely it's due to `DateTimeFormat`, see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60922044/task-not-serializable-with-java-time-in-spark-shell-or-zeppelin-but-not-in-s)

Comment: @jack that's definitely related to the DatetimeFormat, thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the issue is DateTimeFormat which can't be serialized. There are multiple views to resolve this issue. I've decided to move the DateTimeFormat definition to the companion object of the class and that worked for me.